# как в начале файла создать правильно консанту чтобы во всех классах ее использовать?

Tags: php

```
вот так работает 
//2. Подключение файлов системы
    define(ROOT, dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once(ROOT.'/components/Autoload.php');
 
но Warning: Use of undefined constant ROOT - assumed 'ROOT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы обратите внимание на номер строки, в котором выдается данное предупреждение, то заметите, что указывает он на строку `define`, а не на `require_once`.

Если вы пойдете еще дальше, и переведете сообщение, то увидите, что там написано "*неизвестная константа ROOT, предполагается 'ROOT'*".
Параметром директивы `define` является строка с названием константы. А строковый летерал заключается в кавычки. Когда интерпретатор видит нечто без кавычек, то он ищет такую константу и не находит ее. Далее он пишет, что раз уж константа не нашлась, препдоложим, что это строка, ругается и заменяет это дело на `"ROOT"`. Так что в целом далее код работает.

Поэтому исправьте ваше `define(ROOT, ...)`  на `define('ROOT', ...)`